# Are NodeJS intervals ever garbage-collected?

Tags: node.js

I ran today into a bug in my unit tests that took forever to fix: I had a class which set a function as an interval and it was hanging the unit tests of that class indefinitely (I am using mocha).

The code is not the cleanest and it is known to have technical debt and code smells (hi circular references), however I was wondering: Are intervals ever garbage collected, if the class itself is garbage-collected, or do they run until the program is killed ?

Comment: Do you mean interval as in [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) that you would explicitly call [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) on?

Comment: TL;DR; Nope! You've registered them to your event-loop already and they will continue to run till cleared. Do your best to always clean up after you're finished with things to not let that mess pile up. For better clarification why don't you put console.log("I'm looping"); in that interval call and try deleting the class to confirm.